# Nuxt.js google AdSense return error supported one tag

Tags: nuxt.js, adsense

I added config Google Adsense to my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```
head: {
    ...
    script: [
        {
            src: 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js',
            'data-ad-client': process.env.VUE_APP_GA_AD || '',
            async: true,
        },
    ],
},
```

I have an error:

> adsbygoogle.push() error: Only one AdSense head tag supported per
> page. The second tag is ignored.

and warning:

> AdSense head tag doesn't support data-n-head attribute.

In the source of the page, I can see the code added to the head tag:

```
<head>
   ...
   <script data-n-head="ssr" src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" data-ad-client="ca-pub-MY_NUMBER" async>
   ...
</head>
```

How I can resolve it ?

Comment: Did you manage to get your site accepted while having these warnings?

Comment: Google replied that my website did not meet the rules. After that, I didn't try anymore

Comment: Sorry to hear that, It's been a week for me, I guess I'll face the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Warning is expected as nuxt seem to be adding extra attribute. This warning doesn't break ads. It's intended to help catch issues where developers might mistype adsbygoogle data attributes.

As for `Only one AdSense head tag supported per page` again, it shouldn't affect ads. The first head tag should run just fine. Though I'm curious why nuxt.js would insert adsbygoogle it twice.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same errors until I followed the instructions here: https://code-tribe.com/how-to-add-google-adsense-to-nuxt/ and created an app.html file. Adding the Adsense code to the app.html file resolved the errors.